# update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic hangs

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

I upgraded from 18.04 LTS to 20.04.LTS and the system ran fine until a new kernel update showed. Now it hangs on creating the initrd image.

Some details:

```
Calling hook btrfs
Adding binary /bin/btrfs
Adding library-link /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
Adding library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
Adding library-link /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1.1.0
Adding library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1.1.0
Adding library-link /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
Adding library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
Adding library-link /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzo2.so.2.0.0
Adding library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzo2.so.2.0.0
Adding library-link /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1.4.4
Adding library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1.4.4
Calling hook cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf
Calling hook compcache
Calling hook cryptroot
```

Update hangs

When I try to remove the previous kernel 5.4.0-29-generic using apt-get autoremove I get the following even though the 5.4.0-29 kernel is successfully removed.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  amd64-microcode intel-microcode iucode-tool libdbus-glib-1-2 linux-headers-generic thermald
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 4,066 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 116627 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing amd64-microcode (3.20191218.1ubuntu1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing intel-microcode (3.20191115.1ubuntu3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing iucode-tool (2.3.1-1) ...
Removing thermald (1.9.1-1build1) ...
Removing libdbus-glib-1-2:amd64 (0.110-5fakssync1) ...
Removing linux-headers-generic (5.4.0.29.34) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic

Progress: [ 92%] [####################################################################################################################..........]

The update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic created a 0 length file
ll /boot
total 175412
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 May  5 09:33 ./
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root     4096 Apr 29 15:34 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   237718 Apr 22 10:08 config-5.4.0-28-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 May  5 09:25 grub/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 May  5 09:24 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  2 root root 81192806 Apr 29 15:35 initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  2 root root 81192806 Apr 29 15:35 initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic.dpkg-bak
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 May  5 09:29 initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic.new
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Apr 29 15:34 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic
drwx------  2 root root    16384 Sep  3  2018 lost+found/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  4736015 Apr 22 10:08 System.map-5.4.0-28-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 May  5 09:24 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-28-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 11657976 Apr 22 10:43 vmlinuz-5.4.0-28-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Apr 29 15:34 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-28-generic
```

Has anyone else seen this kind of bug?

Comment: Some of your description doesn't make sense... but ignoring that... boot into recovery mode and in `terminal` type `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.4.0-28-generic`, then `reboot`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion heynnema. I reinstalled 20.4 LTS server and restored from backup the critical folders.

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted the system and reinstalled from 20.4 LTS DVD. Then I restored from backup the user files.
This was then resubscribed to canonical-liveupdate. The server is now running 5.4.0-29.